# to_date(to_char(EVT_COMPLETED, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')as "Corrected Completion Date"

Tags: t-sql, plsql

I currently have to convert below statement from oracle to TSQL

```
to_date(to_char(EVT_COMPLETED, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') as "Corrected Completion Date"
```

Can anyone help me on this please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ;). This side does not do your (home) work for you. Please update your question and describe your problem, so we can help you solve it.

Comment: What datatype is EVT_COMPLETED

Comment: evt_completed is datetime and it is showing in database as 2009-05-11 09:40:00.0.  I need this as 11-05-2009 as date.  Thank you Kamran

Comment: Note: `to_date(to_char(...` is equivalent to `TRUNC(EVT_COMPLETED) AS "Corrected Completion Date"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2009-05-11 09:40:00.0'

SELECT @date , CONVERT(varchar,@date,110 ) , CONVERT(varchar,@date,101 ) , CONVERT(date,@date,110 ) , CONVERT(date,@date,101 ), CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,@date,110 ),110 ) , CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,@date,101 ),101 )
```

Results:
[image]

However the data type date will show differently as shown in the above query. So you will need to convert to varchar when showing the data to the user. More info [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Comment: Hi Kamran, I did CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,@date,101 ),101 ) and it is giving me the date as 2009-05-11 and the datatype as date.  However my problem now is I need the datattype to be the same as date but I want the date format to be 11-05-2015 as I will be comparing this date with the last day of the month which is in 31-05-2015.

Comment: @chazpe if both your datatype are of the type date/datetime then you should not have any issues comparing as the format does not effect the values within the type. However if you want to show the user in a particular format then you will need to convert to varchar when showing.

Comment: Thanks Kamran.  I understand.  How do I then convert last_day(EVT_SCHEDEND) AS "Fail_Date" to do the comparison between the dates.  Both the data types should be date to get the correct comparison

Comment: I did below but it is now a character.  I need this to be date datatype please for date comparison.  Convert(Char,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, EVT_SCHEDEND) + 1, 0) - 1,103) AS "Fail_Date"

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2009-05-11 09:40:00.0'
DECLARE @date2 date = '2009-06-11'

select CONVERT(varchar(10), @date,105) where @date2>cast(@date as date)
```

Comment: Hi, I did this and it is converting to the right format of 11-05-2009, but I want the datatype to be date since I will be comparing this date to the last day of the month which is a date datatype

Comment: Still you can compare with this to date data type, you will get results. see Edited.